# ipad wont leave the charging icon

Tags: ipad

Today I wanted to check my social media, but it didn't work. Then I saw the charging icon and it said it was charging, even tho it was unplugged. I tried turning off my ipad, but my ipad didn't allow me to do it. So I decided to restart it from the settings and now it just stuck with the apple logo it's not finishing restarting. What's happening?

Answer (score 1):

hold power+home button simultaneously till the screen turns off (reset).
maybe try restoring your iPad through iTunes to an older backup.iOS Version?it might be a bug with iOS 11.